# terraform for_each index issue, invalid index

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

> The error seems to be same as what is mentioned in this post
> ([Terraform for_each loop. Invalid index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766117/terraform-for-each-loop-invalid-index));
> though answer doesnt seems to be related to what I want to do; so
> posting as new question

```
Terraform version: 0.13.6
aws provider version is: 3.7
```

What Im trying to do is, use a s3 bucket creation module in multiple account. The s3 bucket config, Im keeping it local. S3 bucket name will be passed via variable (list of strings), and if the s3 bucket name/s exist in local s3_buckets variable, the config should be taking from there. for ex, for account 1, only bucket1 will be created, for account2, bucket1 and bucket 3 will be created etc.

Im hoping based on the "var.s3_buckets" value I pass, it will find the right config from local; however, and for some reason, it looks for all values, hence erroring out for with index I think. I think Im missing something, though cant figure out what it is..

The variable Im passing is

```
var.kms_keys = {"bucket2":"org/bucket"}
var.s3_buckets = ["bucket2]
```

The error Im getting is :

```
Error: Invalid index

  on modules/../main.tf line 22, in locals:
  22:       kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket1"].arn
    |----------------
    | aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys is object with 1 attribute "bucket2"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Code is

```
locals {
  s3_buckets = {
    bucket1 = { 
      kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket1"].arn
    },
    bucket2 = { 
      bucket_policy = templatefile("bucket2.json",
        {
          bucket_name = "bucket2"
        }
      )
      kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket2"].arn
    },
    bucket3= { 
      bucket_policy = templatefile("bucket3.json",
        {
          bucket_name = "bucket3"
          kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket3"].arn
        }
      )
      kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket3"].arn
    }

  }
}
.
.
resource "aws_kms_key" "logging_kms_keys" {
  for_each = var.kms_keys

  description         = "${each.value} KMS Key"
  enable_key_rotation = true
  policy              = lookup(local.kms_policies, each.key, "")
  is_enabled          = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "logging_buckets" {
  for_each = toset(var.s3_buckets)

  bucket        = each.key
  acl           = lookup(local.s3_buckets[each.key], "acl", "private")
  policy        = lookup(local.s3_buckets[each.key], "bucket_policy", "")
  force_destroy = false

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = lookup(local.s3_buckets[each.key], "kms_key_arn", data.aws_kms_alias.default_kms_key.arn)
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
      bucket_key_enabled = true
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Its not clear what `var.kms_keys` is?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, its just a map of values, i use it to create KMS key for individual bucket for replication. I use that at later stage to apply to bucket properties (II'm adding that too now), in question. the variable Im passing is included on top of the question, as YAML under the section , "variable im passing is"

Comment: What exactly is it? Can you show the actual, or example values of the `var.kms_keys`?

Comment: Oh, Im sorry, I included that as YAML. it will be like this var.kms_keys = {"bucket2":"org/bucket"}

Comment: In that case the error is clear. In your `var.kms_keys` you have only `bucket2`, but you are trying to access `bucket1` and `bucket3`. Not sure what do you want to do?

Comment: Thats want I'm trying to figure out, why its accessing bucket1 and bucket3?. What Im trying to do is, it should only access what Im passing in var.s3_bucket, which is only bucket2 ?

Comment: because in your locals you have `kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket1"].arn`.

Comment: oh okay, so regardless of if I'm referring it or not, local variables would always initialize first? I thought it would only try to interpolate, if im doing the lookup in the local map (local.s3_buckets). That is, with the passed variable, the code should only look into local.s3_buckets["bucket2"] and its contents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244462/discussion-between-danny-and-marcin).

Answer (score 1):

If you have only `bucket2`, you can't refer to `bucket1` nor `bucket3` in your `locals` as they do not exist. Thus it should be:

```
locals {
  s3_buckets = {
    bucket2 = { 
      bucket_policy = templatefile("bucket2.json",
        {
          bucket_name = "bucket2"
        }
      )
      kms_key_arn = aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket2"].arn
    }
  }
}
```

or you can do it iteratively with `for_each`:

```
locals {
  s3_buckets = { for bucket, kms in aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys:
    "${bucket}" => { 
      bucket_policy = templatefile("${bucket}.json",
        {
          bucket_name = bucket
        }
      )
      kms_key_arn = kms.arn
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay, I think I understand what you meant, that I'm accessing those values from local itself. I see the problem now, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing what Im doing wrong. Im using "try" now, which seems to be working with what I want `kms_key_arn = try(aws_kms_key.logging_kms_keys["bucket1"].arn, null)`  The problem with interpolating with in local is (as what you said as a second method with for_each), I have more than just bucket_name to pass into template file for some bucket policies, and some bucket doesnt even have kms_key_arn

Comment: @Danny I don't know what other things you use in your template. I can only base my answer on what you post in the question. If you have more complex scenario, please make new question with all relevant details.